# How to make deep link for Viber that will redirect to specific number on mobile phones

Tags: hyperlink, uri, deep-linking, viber, viber-api

I need a deep link that will redirect to specific number on Viber. I have for now this, but it's working as it should on computer, not phones.

```html
<a id="viber" href="viber://pa?chatURI=<+38163600583>">Viber</a>
```

I saw this https://developers.viber.com/docs/tools/deep-links/ and edited it as the documentation states, but it's still not working on phones. I tried without and with `+` and without it (the `+` in front of number) or without `<>`, but still not working.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 5):

```
viber://chat?number=911234567890
```

just make sure that number is no having + sign before the country code(91 is counry code here)
i got his from here [Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50418982/5706413)

Answer (score 2):

Suppose your country code is `+84`, and your phone number is `1234567899`.

For PC

```
viber://chat/?number=+841234567899&draft=$hello
```

For Mobile (Android & IOS)
Replace the `+` to `%2B`

```
viber://chat/?number=%2B841234567899&draft=$hello
```