# Launch Viber and send message with link, email, batch in desktop app

Tags: email, notifications, viber, scada, viber-api

In the industrial environment, we have a SCADA system for monitoring temperatures, humidity, and other params. When an alarm comes, I cand send some variables from our software. 
Currently, I have managed to make working with the SMS gateway service. Is it possible to open the Viber desktop app and send some text messages in alarm? I read you could make bot with some PHP application, but I'm not programmer. Any easy solutions?

Refer to this.
[Create a link that will open Viber and WhatsApp and will send a message to me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41324364/create-a-link-that-will-open-viber-and-whatsapp-and-will-send-a-message-to-me)

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can!

Viber has a simple api that you can integrate in your scada. Every connection require a called "viber bot".

Example is in Javascript using node.js framework at serverside but viber offers a variety of ways to integrate.

Check this link!
[Viber Bot Api](https://developers.viber.com/docs/api/nodejs-bot-api/)

Also this tutorial is very helpful! [Build Viber Bot](https://chatbotslife.com/build-viber-bot-with-nodejs-a21487e5b65)